# How get both the vertices and edge value in neptune db

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am new to Neptune DB, I have created vertices and connected two vertices with edges and I have given some properties to both the edge and value

I want to retrieve both the edge and vertices properties values

Can someone provide me a sample query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Eg:
Vertices: p1,  P2, p3
Edges E1-connecting P1 and P2, E2- connecting P2 and P3
Vertices property: name
Edge property: relation

Now I need to take out name and relation for all the vertices connected to P1

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you provide sample graph, starting vertex or property, and expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` step is what you are looking for. Using the `by` modulator you can select properties in a round-robin fashion, i.e. vertex-edge.

Start by locating p1 vertex:

```
g.V().hasLabel("testV").has("name","p1")
```

Repeat traversal along edges with "relation" property:

```
.repeat(outE("testE").has("relation").inV()).until(__.not(outE("testE")))
```

Get the traversal `path` (or `tree`), and select "name" for vertices, and "relation" for edges using the `by` modulator:

```
.path().by("name").by("relation")
```

To see results in arrays of strings:

```
.local(unfold().fold())
```

Note that this traversal doesn't handle cycles, but that's another question.

---

If you need only first level neighbors, you can take a different approach:

```
g.V().hasLabel("testV").has("name","p2").bothE()
.project("relation","name")
.by(values("relation"))
.by(otherV().values("name"))
```

Comment: can I do link this

Comment: g.V().hasLabel("testV").has("name","p1").bothE().otherV().path().by("name").by("relation")

Comment: which one is best and can some one explain why ?

Comment: Of course you can, but you will get only first level neighbors, so in your example it would be only p2, and you will not get p3.

Comment: for now, I need only the first level only.

Comment: The result which I am getting as json response is too complex, can we get only values like p1 relation dad, is that possible, bec in response i am getting path and value that i dont need

Comment: See my updated answer. Would appreciate if you accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the update approach if I more than on condition then I am getting an error. `g.V().hasLabel("testV").has("name",within("p2","p3")).bothE()
.project("relation","name")
.by(values("relation"))
.by(otherV().values("name"))` If you can help this one also it will be great

Comment: Probably not all edges have "relation" property or vertices have "name" property. You can bypass that by adding `has('relation')` before the project and `coalesce` for the name projection.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I am working with a large amount of data so the query is getting slow to execute, how can I optimize the query  `g.V().hasLabel("testV").has("name","p1").bothE().otherV().path().by("name").by("relation")`

Comment: Please open a new question and share information on how many vertices and edges are in your graph, how many first level neighbors, DB engine version, etc. Path is expensive, so might be better to use my other suggested approach.